# How to pass groupId value in @KafkaListener from database?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to connect my spring mvc application with Kafka Server to consume kafka messages. For this I have written KafkaConsumer class as below.

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {
    
    
    @KafkaListener(groupId = "my-group-id", topicPattern = "VID.*", containerFactory = SystemParameterConstants.KAFKA_LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY)
    public void receivedMessage(@Payload String message) {
        logger.info("================ receivedMessage() ==================");
        logger.info("::: Message recieved from kafka ::: {}", message);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            ...
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have hard coded group id **"my-group-id"** but I want to read this groupId from DB so that I can have different groupId for different environment.

Please suggest a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you read from a database instead of an application profile?

Answer (score 5):

See its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Override the {@code group.id} property for the consumer factory with this value
 * for this listener only.
 * <p>SpEL {@code #{...}} and property place holders {@code ${...}} are supported.
 * @return the group id.
 * @since 1.3
 */
String groupId() default "";
```

If you have a bean, which reads data from the DB, then you can do like this:

```
groupId = "#{myDbBean.grouIdFromDb}"
```

See also docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-properties